# Why does the content of the file print only once

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

```
filename='learning_python.txt'
with open(filename) as file_object:
    content=file_object.read()
    print(content)
    lines=file_object.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        print(line.strip())
    file=''
    for line in lines:
        files+=line.strip()
print(file)
```

Comment: Because you're appending to a `files` variable and then printing `file`.

Comment: @Sayse No. Op is not appending anything at all.

Comment: @Psytho - Yes they are, if they weren't they'd get a NameError instead of having it print once.

Comment: @Sayse Nope, there is nothing to append at that point. And if there was THEN there would be a NameError.

Comment: They wouldn't get a NameError if it wouldn't enter their loop which it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the file once, the cursor remains at the last position and all following `readlines()` read nothing. You must return cursor to the beginning of the file using

```
file_object.seek(0)
```

You also need to create `files` variable to be able to append to it:

```
files = []
```